# coupon code only allowed to be used programmatically

Tags: checkout, magento-1, magento-enterprise, shopping-cart-price-rules, coupon

I am looking for a way to have a coupon code that can only be used through code and not be allowed to be used in the cart.  I am programmatically adding the coupon code to the cart when the user is redirected to the site through a 3rd party system to a hidden url.   This way the coupon code can not be distributed on the net and only used when coming from the 3rd party system.

Any idea how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I assume you've got an information in customer session or quote when he comes from the 3rd party system.

You can hook into event `sales_validator_process` at frontend area and cancel a specific coupon (or even go further and set it as a condition).

An observer method could look something like this:

```
public function cancelCouponForFrontendArea(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    /* @var $rule Mage_SalesRule_Model_Rule */
    $rule = $observer->getEvent()->getRule();
    /**
     * @var $quote Mage_Sales_Model_Quote
     */
    $couponCode = $rule->getCode();
    if ($couponCode === 'RTL25OFF') { // or another if statement like if(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getIsFromThirdPartySystem())
        $quote = $observer->getQuote();
        $observer->getResult()->setData(null);
        $quote->setCouponCode(null)->collectTotals()->save();
    }

}
```

Module's config event observer:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <salesrule_validator_process>
            <observers>
                <namespace_module>
                    <class>NameSpace_Module_Model_Observer</class>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <method>cancelCouponForFrontendArea</method>
                </namespace_module>
            </observers>
        </salesrule_validator_process>
    </events>
</frontend>
```

Comment: That works perfectly and only 5 minutes to implement!!!